# phonegap webview can I access response

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap and one of the things we want to do is open an existing web page login screen in a mobile web view.
So through web view when client logs in - is there any way on the mobile I can get a handle that the user has logged in - so that when the user next time launches the application - I do not show the login screen but the screen after login

would that be possible ?
Thanks
akila

Comment: You can use `localStorage` for that. After a successful login, save a token on the user's device. And the next time, before loading the login page, check if the token in the local storage is authentic. If it is, redirect to the profile/home page, else just show the login page. Try this out, and if you're stuck, feel free to let me know, I can help.

Comment: do you have control over the login screen? or is it provided by twitter, facebook or other 3rd party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using phonegap, you will have access to web database which you can use to store things like the login token and other data.

So next time when the user opens the app, you can use the data to verify if the user has already logen in or not and also use the token to invoke the login process which depends on your method of login verification.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks i am very basic here - so web database is on the phone ? similar to sqllite ?so i can check locally ? so from a web view i can come to know if login was successful ( store token ) or unsuccessful ( not store token )

Comment: Yes exactly. There are some options but I personally prefer websql which is simple to use. For iOS and Android, it would be native to the weview and for windows phone you should include the official plugin which could be found here: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql

Comment: An example could be found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_database_database.md.html

Comment: This page contains details about available options for web databases available for PhoneGap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html As I said before, in case of websql for windows phone, you should include a plugin for it to work and it will work cross platform. :)

Comment: Thanks Rojan - just last question - in webview I am opening a login screen of a website - so even then I can understand in phonegap and take decision if user logged in successfully or not ? - sorry to repeat - but just wanted to be clear ! thanks

Comment: Not really. For PhoneGap API to work the cordova.js is essential which is included by the compiler at compile time, so it's not possible to just open a login page from some website and interact with it as it doesn't have cordova.js included. My suggestion is to create your own login page in PhoneGap that calls the login page functionality. Let's say if it's a simple https post, you could do post from your page and results as responses or if it's some login API, call it from JavaScript and do the rest for web database in PhoneGap. Hope you have got the answer to your question now. :)